# Laravel - $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] empty when running queued jobs?

Tags: laravel, macos-sierra

In some of my files I have these sorts of lines:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../vendor/stripe/stripe-php/init.php');
```

Usually all is well. Now I am running some queued jobs, and I am seeing errors of the sort:

> Failed opening required '/../vendor/stripe/stripe-php/init.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/app/Somemodel.php:9

So it is as if when things are executing from artisan `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is empty.
I am on a MAC with Sierra. Maybe there is some setting that I overlooked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queued jobs are running in the background so `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is empty, because it's a path retrieved from the web server directive

It also explains why it's empty when running the Artisan CLI

You can require the file using the `base_path` instead

```php
require_once base_path() . '/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/init.php';
```

Here's the difference in Artisan Tinker

```
~/Sites/laravel (master ✗) ✹ ★ ᐅ  tinker
Psy Shell v0.9.9 (PHP 7.3.9-1~deb10u1 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> require_once base_path() . '/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/init.php';
=> true
>>> require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/init.php';
PHP Fatal error:  Failed opening required '/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/init.php' in Psy Shell code on line 1
>>> $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
=> ""
>>> base_path()
=> "/home/caddy/Sites/laravel"
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense!